# JQuery tabs - unique ID for each container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, uniqueidentifier

In my latest Wordpress project I'm trying to figure out how to use JQuery tabs in combination with the ACF repeater fields. The first one works but now I want multiple divs containing a few tabs on a single page. The following ones don't show the content in tabs (the script is not working on these). As far as I understand this is caused by the ID of the div (#tabs). Therefore I like to add something to this ID to see if this fixes my problem; like #tabs1, #tabs2, #tabs3, etc. I can't give each div it's own ID manually as they are created in a loop (ACF repeater field). Been searching for days and can't seem to find how to do this in the script. Hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

```
<script>                                      
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#tabs').tabs();
   })
</script>
```

The loop to create the tabs:

```
<?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
   <div id="tabs">

      <?php while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
         <div id="<?php the_sub_field('tab_title');?>">
            <?php the_sub_field('tab_content');?>
         </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <ul>
         <?php while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
            <li><a href="#<?php the_sub_field('tab_title');?>"><?php the_sub_field('tab_title'); ?></a></li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>

   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's an example of a website that has a set up kind of like what I'm trying to achieve... note that each section has a slide show with buttons (in my case the 'tabs') underneath to select a different slide show.
http://partnersandspade.com/studio/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, will make a change to the above code... we don't need this part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Changing to class should work but if it doesn't I would suggest to change your ACF structure a bit. You could include the slider repeater in another repeater field "tabs" then you would be able to loop in the loop ([docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) - nested lops) and that way you will give each "tabs" an unique id. See the code below:

```
 <?php if( have_rows('tabs') ): ?>
      <?php $i = 1; while(have_rows('tabs') ): the_row(); ?>
            <div id="tabs<?php echo $i++; ?>">

                 <?php while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
                       <div id="<?php the_sub_field('tab_title');?>">
                             <?php the_sub_field('tab_content');?>
                       </div>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>

                 <ul>
                       <?php while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
                             <li><a href="#<?php the_sub_field('tab_title');?>"><?php the_sub_field('tab_title'); ?></a></li>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                 </ul>

            </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php  endif; ?>
```

I've misunderstood at the first time. Did you consider changing id="tabs" to class="tabs". This should solve the problem:

```
<script>                                      
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    })
</script>
```

Markup:

```
 <div class="tabs">
```

**IGONRE BELOW:**

Add variable $i with value "1" and increase its value on the end on the loop.

Replace

```
<?php the_sub_field('tab_title');?>
```

with

```
tabs<?php echo $i;?>
```

All together this should give you unique id for each row.

```
<?php $i = 1; while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
     <div id="tabs<?php echo $i;?>">
        <?php the_sub_field('tab_content');?>
     </div>
  <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not about the content of #tabs though, but about the actual #tabs div itself. It needs a unique ID in order for the script to work on all. I tried to fiddle around with your suggestion by placing the pieces of code on the #tabs but without luck, all #tabs are now #tabs1. And how does the script know what ID's it needs to 'target'.

Comment: Changing the ID to a class didn't do the trick, did try it already and tried it again just now. Will place an example of the page online later today. Maybe this will clarify things a little more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies here `<div id="<?php the_sub_field('tab_title');?>">`.
If your `tab_title` have spaces, comma, quotes (which is most likely since it's a title and not a slug) and you use it as an element `id` then this isn't valid and will likely cause some problem.

Use simple `ids` instead. `tab-1`, `tab-2`, `tab-2` etc.,

e.g.

```
<?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
   <div id="tabs">

      <?php $i = 1; ?> <!-- initiate the loop count var -->
      <?php while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
        <div id="#tab-<?php echo $i;?>">
          <?php the_sub_field('tab_content');?>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <ul>
        <?php $i = 1; ?> <!-- initiate the loop count var -->
        <?php while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
          <li><a href="#tab-<?php echo $i;?>"><?php the_sub_field('tab_title'); ?></a></li>
          <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>

   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is a good idea and I will use this to create the different tabs. But this doesn't solve the problem. There content already worked and will work even better with your ID suggestion. 

It's about the wrapper div; #tabs. For each chapter a new #tabs will be made containing their tab_content. The first #tabs works fine but the following ones won't work. I think that these need a unique ID, but I might be wrong... The thing I wanted to achieve is to give each loop a unique ID to the tab wrapper (#tabs) and make the script point to these unique ID's. Will place an example online later today.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I'm at now...

I managed to give all tab wrappers (#tabs) it's own ID and all the tabs inside this wrapper will get a unique ID too.

```
<?php $tabsId = 1; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article">
        <header class="article-header">
            <h1 class="h2 entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
         </header>

         <?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
             <div id="tabs<?php echo $tabsId; ?>">

                 <?php $tabId = 1; while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
                     <div id="tab<?php echo $tabId;?>">
                         <?php the_sub_field('tab_content');?>
                     </div>
                 <?php $tabId++; endwhile; ?>

                 <ul class="tabs">
                     <?php $tabId = 1; while(have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
                         <li><a href="#tab<?php echo $tabId;?>"><?php the_sub_field('tab_title'); ?></a></li>
                     <?php $tabId++; endwhile; ?>   
                 </ul>

             </div>
         <?php endif; ?>

         <section class="entry-content cf">
             <?php the_content(); ?>
         </section>

     </article>

 <?php $tabsId++; endwhile; ?>
```

However I think I need to change the script somehow so it knows that I'm not targeting the #tabs div but I'm targeting #tabs1, #tabs2, #tabs3 etc. Here's the script I'm using as i'm using it. Is there way to change this so it runs on each #tabs.. div?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#tabs1').each(function(){
   // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
   // which tab is active and it's associated content
   var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

   // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
   // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
   $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
   $active.addClass('active');
   $content = $($active[0].hash);

   // Hide the remaining content
   $links.not($active).each(function () {
   $(this.hash).hide();
   });

   // Bind the click event handler
   $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
   // Make the old tab inactive.
   $active.removeClass('active');
   $content.hide();

   // Update the variables with the new link and content
   $active = $(this);
   $content = $(this.hash);

   // Make the tab active.
   $active.addClass('active');
   $content.show();

   // Prevent the anchor's default click action
   e.preventDefault();
   });
});
})
```

Comment: Add `class` to your tabs element `<div class="tab" id="tabs<?php echo $tabsId; ?>">` and change you jQuery code to target all `.tab` in your each() loop like: `$('.tab').each(function()`.